# How to reset label generated in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I click a button it start a function with an infinite loop. In the loop I scrape various URLs, I save the URLs in a list, pass the list to another function that displays the labels in the GUI. The problem is after each iteration in the infinite loop the labels get appended in the GUI instead of refreshing the label values. I tried using `.config(text="something")` but still doesn't refresh and just appends generating a new label.

```
from os import link
import tkinter as tk
import selenium.webdriver
import time
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image
import webbrowser

running = True 

def on_open():
    global driver

    if running:
        
            driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome('location')
            url = "whatever"
            driver.get(url)
            
            accept = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ButtonPrimitive__StyledButtonPrimitive-sc-1lbd19y-0 kTFzpu']").click()
            
            time.sleep(5)
            fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='Heading__StyledHeading-sc-rrd5d-0 jTFrNP']")
        
            links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='PictureCardstyled__StyledPictureCard-sc-1i137c0-0 dnbSjQ']")
            hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in links]

            
            #LINKURI
            n = len(hrefs)
            linkuri = []

            for i in range(n):
                linkuri.append(hrefs[i])

            #TITLURI
            n = len(fields)

            element = []
            for i in range(n):
                element.append(fields[i].text)
                
            
            driver.close()
            
            labelsVacante(linkuri,element)
            root.after(5000, on_open)

def labelsVacante(element,linkuri):
    
    convertToTuple(element)
    convertToTuple(linkuri)

    qtextnlinks=tuple(zip(linkuri,element))

      
    for label_text, url in qtextnlinks:
        label_p = tk.Label(root, text=label_text, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        label_p.pack()
        label_p.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, url=url: webbrowser.open_new(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `tk.label` 'textvariable' attribute?

```
def labelsVacante(element,linkuri):
    convertToTuple(element)
    convertToTuple(linkuri)

    qtextnlinks=tuple(zip(linkuri,element))

    label_var = tk.StringVar()  # create a variable to store the text
      
    for label_text, url in qtextnlinks:
        label_var.set(label_text)  # set the variable to the new 'label_text'
        label_p = tk.Label(
            root,
            text=label_text,  # you may not need this any more, but it won't hurt anything
            textvariable=label_var,  # use your new variable as the 'textvariable'
            fg="blue",
            cursor="hand2"
        )
        label_p.pack()
        label_p.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, url=url: webbrowser.open_new(url))
```

The label's text should now change whenever `label_var` is updated

Comment: unfortunately, it's not working. The text still gets appended instead of updating and messes up the label text and it creates multiple labels with the same text(last text in my tuple)

For testing purposes, qtextnlinks looks like this: qtextnlinks=( ("a","youtube.com"),("b","google.com"),("c","bing.com") ) Code will display 3 c's opening different link on click

Comment: As a test, I tried `for label_text, url in qtextnlinks: print(label_text, url)` but that had issues because `qtextnlinks` is  a tuple of tuples. Have you tried declaring `qtextnlinks` as a list instead? `qtextnlinks = [("a", "youtube.com"), ("b", "google.com"), ("c", "bing.com")]` -> `qtextnlinks = list(zip(linkuri, element))`

Comment: same behaviour. Hardcoded  `textnlinks = [("a", "youtube.com"), ("b", "google.com"), ("c", "bing.com")] -> qtextnlinks = list(zip(linkuri, element))` and the text still gets appended instead of updating and it creates multiple labels with the same text(last text in list, 3 c's)

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment may have been unclear. `qtextnlinks = list(zip(linkuri, element))` should replace `qtextnlinks = tuple(zip(linkuri, element))`...the hardcoded list was just an example. Unfortunately I can't run your code as-is, so I can't test it.